# Does scale up or down images effect image information?

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network

i'm work on graduation project for **image forgery detection using CNN** , Most of the paper i read before feed the data set to the network they Down scale the image size, i want to know how Does this process effect image information ?

Comment: What papers have you read and do they pertain to image forgery detection specifically or just the use of CNN's for image analysis?

Comment: paper for example  https://github.com/agusgun/FakeImageDetector/blob/master/docs/Deteksi%20Pemalsuan%20Gambar%20dengan%20ELA%20dan%20Deep%20Learning.pdf
not only forgery detection but Also All image classification papers

Comment: Is there an English version of that paper you could link by chance?

Comment: @Piglet the third point in my answer explains how. This wasn't necessarily a question about downsampling vs interpolation, but the effect that resizing an image before feeding it into a network has on it's features. Feature extraction from super-resolution imagery isn't really a thing since you're are guessing what is between pixels. For this reason I only covered downsampling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are resized/rescaled to a specific size for a few reasons:

(1) It allows the user to set the input size to their network. When designing a CNN you need to know the shape (dimensions) of your data at each step; so, having a static input size is an easy way to make sure your network gets data of the shape it was designed to take.

(2) Using a full resolution image as the input to the network is very inefficient (super slow to compute).

(3) For most cases the features desired to be extracted/learned from an image are also present when downsampling the image. So in a way resizing an image to a smaller size will denoise the image, filtering out much of the unimportant features within the image for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you change the images size. Of course it changes it's information.

You cannot reduce image size without omitting information. Simple case: Throw away every second pixel to scale image to 50%.

Scaling up adds new pixels. In its simplest form you duplicate pixels, creating redundant information.

More complex solutions create new pixels (less or more) by averaging neighbouring pixels or interpolating between them.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling up is reversible. It doesn't create nor destroy information.

Scaling down divides the amount of information by the square of the downscaling factor*. Upscaling after downscaling results in a blurred image.

(*This is true in a first approximation. If the image doesn't have high frequencies, they are not lost, hence no loss of information.)

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to what's been stated in some of the answers, scaling up can be irreversable as well, and there would be information loss when it is. This is why interpolation is used when scaling up.

If you scale up a pixel by a square of an integer (example: 2x2=4, 3x3=9, 4x4=16 etc), scaling up will be reversible, because for every pixel, you end up with an integer number of new pixels. But other than that, when you scale up, some pixels will end up getting divided between multiple pixels and interpolated.

This is similar to the phenomenon of being able to see relatively sharper graphics when a display is 4K with the resolution set to FHD. This is because 4K has exactly 4 times the pixels as FHD. However, if the resolution is set to FHD on a 1440p screen, graphics get blurry, and in order for it to not get blurry, additional processing power is required.